# How to extract curl request response

Tags: json, regex, parsing, curl, extract

Am trying below curl request:

```
curl -s https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Xv0kgJUNq/?igshid=2zc9h1kyhkyv | grep commentCount
```

How to get the value number of `"commentCount":"26508"` in the curl response.

I've tried above command it getting me the full JSON `<script type="application/ld+json">` .. while I just need the count of "commentCount" value.

Comment: You could pipe this command into `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

An HTML *and* JSON parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) would fit the job:

```
$ xidel -s "https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Xv0kgJUNq/?igshid=2zc9h1kyhkyv" -e '
  parse-json(
    //script[@type="application/ld+json"]
  )/commentCount
'
```

Answer (score 0):

with Linux grep you can

```
$ curl -s https://www.instagram.com/p/B_Xv0kgJUNq/?igshid=2zc9h1kyhkyv | grep -Po 'commentCount":"\K\d*'
99795
```

Comment: btw the jq path is ```.entry_data.PostPage[0].graphql.shortcode_media.edge_media_to_parent_comment.count```